Ag-Grid infinite scroll appends data, but scrolls back to first row
The problem:
As the user scrolls down the page, we make a service call that succeeds and appends the data to the "rowData" property and the grid is populated with the correct data, but the grid scrolls up to the first row.
The question:
How do I prevent the grid from scrolling up to the first row? I would either like to stay at the current scrolled position or scroll to a specific "row-id".
Other details:
I'm using Angular v17 and the latest version of ag-grid (31.2.0) and
the client-side infinite scroll strategy. It was working as expected in the previous version I was using Angular v15 and ag-grid (28.2.1)
Populating grid on scroll
if (changes.rowData) {
    if (this.rowData && this.rowData.length === 0) {
        this.gridApi?.showNoRowsOverlay();
    } else if (this.rowData && this.rowData.length > 0 && !this.gridApi.isDestroyed()) {
        this.loading = false;
        this.agGridUpdatedData = [...this.agGridUpdatedData, ...this.rowData];
        this.gridApi.applyTransactionAsync({add: this.agGridUpdatedData});
        this.rowData = this.agGridUpdatedData;
    }
}


This post was what helped me solve my issue with scrolling.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723337/ag-grid-how-to-scroll-to-last-known-position

I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038909/row-moves-to-top-after-editing-in-ag-grid
